# Why does the Photoshop Fill tool change pixels outside of the boundary I'm filling?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, tools, fill, pixel-art

In the example image, I am trying to fill a white area and the black pixel lines around it are being changed. Also, there are a few gray pixels created at the bottom corners, outside my outline. Why is all this happening and how can I prevent it?

[image]

Comment: Hi sketcherskt, welcome to GDSE. I went ahead and edited your question for clarity. If I mangled anything beyond your intention of recognition, feel free to roll back my edit or [edit] the question again.

Comment: thanks for making my question more clearly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top of the screen, just below the pull-down menus. In the bar over there, once you select the fill tool, there is a tickbox labeled 'anti-alias'. Untick that.

Comment: Thank you so much!